# Block the interface while process is running in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have the following procedure which helps me execute a bat file. What I need is that when this procedure is called, until it's finished, for the user not to be able to work on anything, something like a loading icon..

Any idea on how to reach this?

```
procedure RunAnalysis(ACommandLine: string);
var
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation;
begin
  FillChar(StartupInfo, SizeOf(StartupInfo), 0);
  StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);

  UniqueString(ACommandLine);

  if CreateProcess(nil, PChar(ACommandLine), nil, nil, False,
    0, nil, nil, StartupInfo, ProcessInfo) then
  begin
    while WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, 10) > 0 do
      Application.ProcessMessages;

    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
  end
  else
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

Comment: Show a modal form to block the user from doing anything.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan but the user can easily close the modal forma..

Comment: It's a progress form. The user can close it by cancelling. You then terminate the child process. Certainly calling `ProcessMessages` isn't terribly cute.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, no, actually we want to force the user to not terminate it

Comment: So show a modal form that cannot be closed. Think a little.

Answer (score 0):

you can call your procedure from a click button and disable yourform until finiched :

```
procedure yourform.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Bat:string;
begin
Bat:={yourCommandLine};
yourform.Enabled:=false;
RunAnalysis(Bat);
yourform.Enabled:=true;
end;
```